# String conversion which is different between HTML and javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

On a .cshtml file, the conversion of an UTF-8 string is not the same between the HTML code and the javascript code.

But I should use a string in javascript to filter a table in HTML, which is impossible with this problem.

For example :

This is a .cshtml file :

```
@{
    string WaitText = "Payé";
}
 
<div>
    @WaitText
</div>
<script>
    @WaitText
</script>
```

And the result on Firefox :

```
<div>
    Payé
</div>
<script>
    Pay&#xE9;
</script>
```

Comment: try use in script `@Html.Raw(WaitText)` this is not escaped value and work for me

Comment: Perfect, it's working. Thank you.
But why we have this behaviour ?

Comment: FYI When rendering a Razor Page, the framework's default behavior is to HTML-encode values within a <script> tag for security reasons also XSS attack